# Why is it that the output of the provided program prints "1:1, 2:1, 3:2, -1:1" and not "0:2, 1:1, 2:1, 3:2, -1:1"?

Tags: python, class, if-statement

So here is the code provided. I tested a few things myself. I learned that if I add a print(i) after (for i in L) it will print the zeros, but if I add print(i) after (if i:) then it doesn't print the zeros. I have searched the internet and my textbook, but I cannot reason this out on my own. What exactly does "if L:" and "if i:" do? Any help would be great, thanks.

```
class TestClass(object):
      def __init__(self,L=None):
          self.D = {}
          if L:
              for i in L:
                  if i:
                      if i in self.D:
                          self.D[i] += 1
                      else:
                          self.D[i] = 1
      def __add__(self,param):
          if type(param) == TestClass:
              for k, v in param.D.items():
                  if k in self.D:
                      self.D[k] += v
                  else:
                      self.D[k] = v
              return TestClass(self.D)
          else:
              return self + TestClass(param)

      def __str__(self):
          out_str = ''
          for k, v in self.D.items():
              out_str += '{}:{}, '.format(k, v)
          out_str = out_str.strip(", ")
          return out_str

inst1 = TestClass([-1,0,0,1,2,3,3])
print(inst1)
```

Comment: `0` is treated as `False` in python so `if i:` will only be `True` if `i` is non-zero. In addition, an empty list `[]` and `None` are both considered `False` so `if L:` will only be `True` if the list `L` is not empty and not `None`.

Comment: @AChampion Thank you so much. That helps a ton!!! I am assuming that this is the same with sets, tuples, dictionaries, etc? And the same if a variable = 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i is zero and will be treat as False, remove this line and you will be fine.

```
if i:
```